# Possible to arrange hour,minute to its own column

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-formula, formula

I have no prior knowledge, and need help in solving this problem where I have to arrange, times :- hour and minute, to its respective column.

[Sample_Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3nbY.png)

Comment: in D3 `=IF(AND(HOUR($B3)=$G$1,MINUTE($B3)=D$3),MINUTE($B3),"")`

Comment: It seems to me I already saw this very same question not so long ago. In any case, if you need a VBA assistance you must come with your code attempts and related issues

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `hour()` and `minute()` functions. You have no past knowledge... but if you couldn't find this answer on your own, perhaps you should take a course in Excel?